# python: adding a number for the class instance variable name

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to count birthdays within a class. I would like to have the year as one of the elements in the class instance like this:

```
{'city': 'New York', '2000': 0}
```

...where '2000' increments with new data

But instead I can only get:

```
{'city': 'New York', 'year': 2000}
```

---

```
class birthyear():
    def __init__(self,city,year):
        self.city = city

        #Why can't I do it 'manually' like so?:
        #self.'2000' = 0
        #Of course this works, but it is not what I need for further incrementing
        self.year = year
by = birthyear('New York',2000)
print (by.__dict__)
```

Comment: `self.year = self.year += 1` ???? just `self.year += 1`

Comment: `2000` cannot be a key, as it is a value not a variable name.

Comment: A variable name or a property of a class (or a function for that matter) can not begin with a number in python syntax. Applying `self.year = year` results in `'year': 2000` within the `__dict__`. That's how python works

Comment: why do you need that wierd format?

Comment: So there is no possible way in python to get this result?
{'city': 'New York', '2000': 1}

Answer (score 0):

No need for iteration. Just type:

> self.year = years

So, code would be:

```
class birthyear():
    def __init__(self,city,years):
        self.city = city
        self.year = years
    def yearCount(year):
        self.year += 1
```

Also, no need for list when you creating new instance.

```
>>> bh = birthyear('Nis', 2000)
>>> bh.__dict__
{'city': 'nis', 'year': 2000}
```

Comment: The problem was how to make it :
{'city': 'nis', '2000': 0}
not
{'city': 'nis', 'year': 2000}

Comment: Oh I misunderstand it. Why would you like to do that? Say what you had in mind, there is probably better way to do it.

Comment: Im simply counting data per year. There are much simpler ways to do this, but I would like to use OOP as it is part of a larger project

Comment: So, is this okay?